# How can I install Windows Phone 8 development application without visual studio

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have developed a windows phone 8 application. I have a developer account and unlocked device. Now I'm able to deploy/install the application in my phone through windows phone development sdk.

Now I want to install this application in another device ( a device of my friend, who is in different location). I don't want to put this application in the app store. I want to mail the XAP file only to him. So is there any other way to install this (XAP file) application in his mobile.

I am looking forward your responses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Your friend has to unlock his device with a developer account in order to install it. Can use the "Application Deployment Tool" to install the XAP.
(This goes well only if your friend is a developer)

**Answer 2: (Easiest way for your friend to install)**

You can release a beta in the store, and include the Microsoft ID of your friend as a beta tester. And after releasing the app, you can email the link to your friend. Beta release is fast and it usually goes live within 1 hour.

Comment: For Answer 1 Has My friend to unlock his device with same developer account which one I used? Or any other account he can use?

Comment: Any developer account.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot (y).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[Targeted distribution to customers with specified email addresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt185377.aspx)".
That means that you will publish the app on the store, but it will only be available for the users that you want.